# Formula bar view changes when document is saved and reopened

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have an Excel 2007 document with a lot of formulas of the format:

```
SUMIFS(view1[COLUMN1],view1[COLUMN2],$C13,view1[COLUMN3],I$10)
```

but when I save the sheet and reopen it each formula is changed to the much less readable (but still accurate) format:

```
SUMIFS(data!$F$2:$F$65536,data!$B$2:$B$65536,$C13,data!$K$2:$K$65536,I$10)
```

The formulas all still work, I just want to keep the view as `view1[COLUMN1]` to make it more readable and to make edits easier.

How do I stop Excel from automatically changing how this shows up in the formula bar?

Comment: If view1 is a named table, go to the Office button-->options-->formula tab-->second header from the top and you'll find a box option with something like "use tables name in formula" (sorry I cannot be more precise, my Excel version is not in English)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the Microsoft office Button and select Excel Options. Choose the Formulas category and in the "Working with formulas Section", select the "Use table names in formulas" option.